# What is wrong with this Javascript code to insert data into a Web SQL database?

Tags: javascript, html, web-sql

I am trying to create a simple page that takes a binary file and inserts the values into a Web SQL database.
This is the function I am using to insert the data:

```
function bin2dbfunc()
{
    var result, n, aByte, byteStr;
    var i=0;
    var sql = new Array();

    result = fr.result;  //Input file

    for (n = 0; n < result.length; ++n) 
    {
        aByte = result.charCodeAt(n);
        byteStr = aByte.toString(16);
        if (byteStr.length < 2)
        {
            byteStr = "0" + byteStr;
        } //Format to add leading 0 for hex values

        //Looping through taking each byte read from file and adding to array

        //sql[i] = aByte;   //Value
        sql[i] = byteStr;   //String


        //When completed one row of database run single SQL insert statement with array contents
        if(i==15)
        {
            i=0;  //Clear counter for next row
            db.transaction(function (tx)
            {
                tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO binary_data VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)', [sql[0], sql[1], sql[2], sql[3], sql[4], sql[5], sql[6], sql[7], sql[8], sql[9], sql[10], sql[11], sql[12], sql[13], sql[14], sql[15]]);
            }, function (tx, err) {
                document.getElementById("result3").innerHTML += 'ERROR ';  //Display error message if SQL not run successfully
            });
        }
        else
        {
            i++;  //Otherwise increment counter
        }
    }
}
```

I have stripped back the code to remove all my debug messages but essentially the code appears to run. I am using a binary file with 6 rows worth of data, the code however inserts the last row of data 6 times into the database.
Can anyone spot where I am going wrong?

Comment: Sounds like a scoping issue - is `db.transaction()` an asynchronous function?

Comment: The variable `i` does not increment if `tx.executeSql` throws an error. Could that be it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Variables are captured by reference and not by value in JavaScript closures (this is true for objects such as arrays but for primitive values as well); this means that the functions passed to `db.transaction` will use the current value of `sql` when they run. It seems that they run asynchronously in your case, thus using the value of `sql` once `bin2dbfunc` has returned (which explains why you end up with the last row of data).

You have to copy the value of `sql` in order to make sure that the right one is used:

```
function transactionCallback(sql_) {
  var sql = sql_.slice(0); // copy
  return function(tx) {
    tx.executeSql(…, sql);
  };
}

db.transaction(transactionCallback(sql), …);
```

or

```
function transactionCallback(sql) {
  return function(tx) {
    tx.executeSql(…, sql);
  };
}

db.transaction(transactionCallback(sql), …);
sql = [];
```

as you don't need `sql`'s values afterwards in `bin2dbfunc`; this second solution would also enable you to get rid of `i` and use a more elegant solution based on `push` and `length`.

Comment: Thank you, that fixed the issue. I will have to do a little more reading before trying any more javascript, this was just a bit of a mash up of examples to try out an idea.